# Problem with 'TreeView' removing child node

Tags: c#, wpf

I was encountering a problem when I collapsed or expanded the root node of the 'TreeView' without selecting any item. This issue was due to my application triggering a drag and drop every time the left mouse button was pressed. This meant that 'droppedData' was always initialized with the last 'MyItem' that was moved, even if no item was selected. The solution that solved my problem was to check if the mouse had been moved a certain distance before starting the drag and drop, so as not to trigger a drag and drop when the mouse is simply moved to collapse or expand the root node.

Best regards,

The problematic code :

```cs
private void TreeView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var treeViewItem = GetNearestContainer(e.OriginalSource as UIElement);
            if (treeViewItem == null) return;

            MyItem clickedItem = treeViewItem.DataContext as MyItem;
            if (clickedItem != null && clickedItem.CanBeDragged)
            {
                _draggedItem = clickedItem;
            }
        }

private void TreeView_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && _draggedItem != null)
            {
                // Commencer le déplacement
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(MyTreeView, _draggedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
                _draggedItem = null; // Clear the item after drag operation
            }
        }
```

The corrected code :

```
private Point? _mouseDownPosition;
    
    private void TreeView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var treeViewItem = GetNearestContainer(e.OriginalSource as UIElement);
        if (treeViewItem == null) return;

        MyItem clickedItem = treeViewItem.DataContext as MyItem;
        if (clickedItem != null && clickedItem.CanBeDragged)
        {
            _draggedItem = clickedItem;
        }

        // Stockez la position de la souris lorsque le bouton de la souris est enfoncé
        _mouseDownPosition = e.GetPosition(MyTreeView);
    }

    private void TreeView_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && _draggedItem != null)
        {
            // Vérifiez si la souris a été déplacée d'une certaine distance avant de commencer le glisser-déposer
            var mouseMovePosition = e.GetPosition(MyTreeView);
            var diff = _mouseDownPosition - mouseMovePosition;
            if (_mouseDownPosition.HasValue && (Math.Abs(diff.Value.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
                Math.Abs(diff.Value.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
            {
                // Commencer le déplacement
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(MyTreeView, _draggedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
                _draggedItem = null; // Clear the item after drag operation
                _mouseDownPosition = null; // Clear the mouse down position
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should implement inotifypropertychanged in my item. Even if you don't need it to notify of property changes. Memory leak is likely otherwise.

Comment: You should reduce the code you show in the question to just what is necessary to reproduce the issue. It's not clear what code is actually giving you the problem. You may be lucky and someone is willing to paste everything in and debug it all for you. But I wouldn't rely on that if I were you.